# Access nested JSON object where object name is always different

Tags: jquery, json, wikipedia-api

I'm trying to access a nested JSON object from the Wikipedia API where the object name is the primary key.

Example:

```
{
    "pages": {
        "13595": {
        "pageid": 13595,
        "ns": 0,
        "title": "London Heathrow Airport",
        "extract": "London Heathrow Airport (IATA: LHR, ICAO: EGLL) is a major international airport in West London, England, United Kingdom."
        }
    }
}
```

13595 is the pageid and is always different for each page. I want to get the value of "extract".

Any Idea how? I'm using jQuery.

Comment: does the object name always equal the pageid as shown in your example?

Comment: Yeah it always will be. Slightly annoying it does that, but I found a way to get it (see answer below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have looked at [How to access nested object in JSON returned by Wikipedia API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10678274/how-to-access-nested-object-in-json-returned-by-wikipedia-api)

Solved by:

```
for (var id in pages){
    var extract = pages[id].extract;
    if (extract){
        $('#txt_airport_extract').text(extract);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're sure that there'll be only one page, the following instruction  returns "13595" in your example:

```
var json = { ... }
Object.keys(json["pages"])[0]
```